# On Roll20, is it possible to fill in character sheets without being in a game?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, character-sheets, roll20

I played Pathfinder on Roll20 last night for the first time and everyone had to wait for me to make a character. I was unfamiliar with the character sheets and with Pathfinder so it took a while. The game invite said they welcomed newcomers, but it was kind of stressful to make everyone wait while I tried to figure stuff out.

I know there are tutorial videos for the Roll20 character sheet and I can read the Core Rulebook, but is there no way to get hands on with the Roll20 character sheets without making people wait for a game?

Answer (score 12):

Once you are a member of a campaign and the GM has created and enabled a character for you, you can log in anytime and update it. Ask the GM to do this a few days before the session and you can set up the character in your own time.

Answer (score 5):

Even with a free account, you should have the ability to make your own game instance, set it to use Pathfinder character sheets and then practice as much as you need.  You won't be able to migrate it over to the game you're playing in however.  I'm not sure if the transmogrifier option on pro/mentor accounts can transfer the sheet to an instance you don't own.

Comment: I might add to this answer that if you have a Plus Account, you can save your character sheets and import them into someone else's game if the game has that setting toggled on. That said, there's no guarantee that the game you're joining is using the same *type* of character sheet. Once you're familiar with the sheet, it should only take you 10 minutes to fill out though.

Comment: So if I create an account in order to practice making characters, I won't be flooded with people expecting me to GM the game? Does creating the game cause it to be advertised to others or is that a separate step (a step I can just not do since I'm not trying to play)?

Comment: @JohnnyRelentless I believe you have to actively invite people in order for them to find the session.  Just making one on your own shouldn't open public floodgates.

Comment: Maximillian is correct, I have a couple games that only my friends are in that are not viewable publicly.